# Is it possible to get access token for Azure Blob Storage using OAuth - Client Credential Grant Type?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-msal

I am preparing the access to **authorizate request** for my external storage in **Azure Blob**. I would like a service application to access that storage using **OAuth** and, as the access is being done by a service (no real user executing the service), I would like to use the [**Client Credential Grant type**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4). I am using Azure Active Directory to manage the users and application registration and permission, so the authorization endpoint will be Azure and it will grant me the access token.

I have used for other services other OAuth credential accesses like [**Authorization Code Grant**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) (I can´t use it in this case because it needs a user to sign-in manually) and even [**Resource Owner Password Credential Grant**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) (is not recommended but I manage both service and storage so it could be implemented. Downside, the application signs-in as a user and I would prefer not to because of security matters.)

I have followed [Microsoft´s guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app) to try to achieve this but still no luck. When following the guide and registrating the API in Azure I can only choose Delegated permissions and not Application permissions that is the one that fits these needs, attached a couple of screnshoots.

[App registration in Azure Active Directory window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77V2l.png)

[App registration options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1xZA.png)

So, all in all, I am trying to implement the **Client Credential type** and I am not able to get a valid token. Is it possible to get the authorization using this type? If yes, could you give me a quick guide or something?

Thank you

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Azure storage, this may be different from other authorization methods. You cannot directly grant Application permissions to your service application in API permissions. This is because your application does not have an RBAC role.

If you are ready to access an authorization request for external storage in Azure Blob, please follow the procedure below [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json):

Azure portal>storage accounts>Search and select your storage accounts>access control(IAM)>Add role assignment to add a service principal to your storage account (this is equivalent to you granting `application permissions` to your service application in `API permissions`)

Then we use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to test in postman:

[image]

By the way, you should refer to this document: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-msi?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)

Comment: Solved, I had to add the version 2017-11-09 or upper to do the get. It was specified in the documentation you added

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your error. if it just says access denied, then just add the service principal to the rbac role of the blob or storage account you are trying to access. then your application should have permissions to call the storage

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to get the token. After following the whole guide, whenver I try to get a token, through postman or through code using [*MSAL libraries*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries)  instead of receiving a token, I receive a redirection to a sign-in window.

The real question is to know if it is possible to do the **Client Grant authentication**? And if it is possible, how?